# Time Complexity of Subset-Sum Enumeration

Tags: algorithm, big-o, enumeration, subset-sum

Normally, when dealing with combinations, the Big-O complexity seems to be *O(n choose k)*. In this algorithm, I am generating all the combinations within the array that match the target sum:

```
def combos(candidates,start, target):
    if target == 0:
        return [[]]
    res = []
    for i in range(start,len(candidates)):
        for c in combos(candidates, i+1, target-candidates[i]):
            res.append([candidates[i]]+ c)
    return res


print combos([2,1,10,5,6,4], 10)
# [[1, 5, 4], [10], [6, 4]]
```

I am having a hard time determining Big-O here, is this a `O(n choose t)` algorithm? If not, what is it and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the point is to give the worst-cast complexity in terms of the set size, *n*, then it is *Θ(2<sup>n</sup>)*. Given any set, if the target sum is large enough, you'll end up enumerating all the possible subsets of the set. This is *Θ(2<sup>n</sup>)*, as can be seen in two ways:

- Each item can be chosen or not.
- It is your *Θ(n choose k)*, just summed up over all *k*.

---

A more refined bound would take into account both *n* and the target sum *t*. In this case, following the reasoning of the 2nd point above, then if all elements (and target sum) are positive integers, then the complexity will be the sum of *Θ(n choose k)* for *k* summing only up to *t*.

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm is at least `O(2^n)` and I believe it is `O(n * 2^n)`. Here is an explanation.

In your algorithm you have to generate all possible combinations of a set (except of an empty set). So this is:

[image]

`O(2^n)` at least. Now for every combinations you have to sum them up. Some sets are of length 1 on is of length `n`, but majority of them would be somewhere of length `n/2`. So I believe that your complexity is close to the `O(n * 2^n)`.

Comment: I don't follow the last summation step above, so out of curiosity (since I probably just don't understand), what sum rule are you using here? (Something in the context of sets and permutations?). The closest I can think of is the finite series `sum_{i=0}^n 2^i = 2^{n+1}-1` or `sum_{i=0}^n a^i = (a^{n+1}-1)/(a-1)` (`a>1`), but none of those really apply to yield the result of your sum above. Thanks!

Comment: @dfri are you speaking about `sum(C_n^i)`? If so than this is a sum of binomials. Check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient right after `Series involving binomial coefficients`.